# Установка свойства IsEnabled MenuItem класса MainWindow в UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть класс MainWindow, главная форма и есть дочерний контрол, который лежит в папке Control в одном проекте. Как установить значение свойства IsEnabled MenuItem класса MainWindow в классе дочернего контрола?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MItem.IsEnabled = false;
   }
}

public partial class ChildWindow : UserControl
{
     MainWindow mw = new MainWindow;
     public void X()
     {
          mw.MItem.IsEnabled = true; // не работает
     }
}
```

**Дополнено из комментария**.

```
public Child(MainWindow mw)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = this;

    mw.MItem.IsEnabled = true;

}
```

Пишет ошибку

> The type 'Сhild' cannot have a Name attribute. Value types and types without a default constructor can be used as items within a ResourceDictionary.

Ссылается как я понял на Control который у меня используется в XAML

```
<Control:Child x:Name="gChild" Height="681">
    <Control:Child.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WpfApp;component/Images/Image.jpg" >
        </ImageBrush>
    </Control:Child.Background>
</Control:Child>
```

Comment: Не создавайте MainWindow, а передавайте его дочернему окну, например, через конструктор.

Comment: А пример можно, что-то у меня не получается передать через конструктор.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795382.aspx

Comment: Я пишу на Framework 3.5 и в XAML у меня нету таких директив. И как применить этот код в моем случае, я что-то не совсем понимаю.

Answer (score 2):

Конструктор - это слишком рано, контрол еще не лег в иерархию. Нужно обрабатывать событие `Loaded` - это признак окончания загрузки XAML и вся структура уже доступна. Обработчик события можно добавить в XAML или в конструкторе. В обработчике события `Loaded` в `ChildWindow` напишите:

```
var mainWnd = Window.GetWindow(this) as MainWindow;
mainWnd.MItem.Enabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте свойство (ну или поле) `MItem public static` и если главное окно не равно `null`, то обращайтесь к нему `MainWindow.MItem = ...`

Comment: Сделал свойство, но не работает: значение не устанавливается в true


    public static bool MItem;

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.MenItem.IsEnabled = MItem;
        }
    }


    public partial class ChildWindow : UserControl
    {
        public void X()
        {
            if (mw != null)
            {
                 MainWindow.MItem = true;
            }
        }
    }

Comment: это неправильно! Зачем вы устанавливаете MItem в true? вам нужно напрямую MenItem.IsEnabled устанавливать в тру, а не MItem. От изменения значения MItem параметр this.MenItem.IsEnabled не изменится